# Distribution of a dice pool

Tags: distributions, polynomial, dice, piecewise-pdf

The article [Three Basic Distributions](https://anydice.com/articles/three-basic-distributions) from [AnyDice](https://anydice.com) shows the distributions (and cumulative distributions) of 1d10, 2d10 and 3d10.

Looking at the graphs, it seems there is a pattern here:

- 1d10: the distribution is a piecewise polynomial with 1 piece of degree 0 (a constant)
- 2d10: the distribution is a piecewise polynomial with 2 pieces of degree 1 (2 linear functions)
- 3d10: the distribution may be a piecewise polynomial with 3 pieces of degree 2

Therefore it seems like distributions of dice pools are piecewise polynomials.
Is it true?

Is there a general formula for the distribution of dice pools?

Answer (score 0):

In the continuous case this is the [Irwin-Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution#Definition) distribution which indeed has a pdf which can be written as a spline.